# Свернуть колонки по агрегации обновляя значения, но пропуская null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица:

```
+-----+---------+------+----------+
| Agg | Version | Col1 |   Col2   |
+-----+---------+------+----------+
| a   |       1 | 12   | "hi1"    |
| a   |       2 | null | "hi2"    |
| b   |       1 | 1    | "bText"  |
| b   |       2 | 5    | null     |
| b   |       3 | null | "bText2" |
+-----+---------+------+----------+
```

необходимо сделать вьюху или функцию, где результат из таблицы свернуть до уникальных значений в Agg и так, чтобы значения в ColN было последним по колонке Version . null учитывать не нужно (кроме случая, где все значения пустые). В итоге должна получиться таблица:

```
+-----+---------+------+----------+
| Agg | Version | Col1 |   Col2   |
+-----+---------+------+----------+
| a   |       2 |   12 | "hi2"    |
| b   |       3 |    5 | "bText2" |
+-----+---------+------+----------+
```

Сервер MS SQL 2016

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее **версия**.?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Внес изменения в вопрос. MS SQL 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Agg,
       MAX(Version) OVER (PARTITION BY Agg) Version,
       FIRST_VALUE(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY Agg ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Version END DESC) col1,
       FIRST_VALUE(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY Agg ORDER BY CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Version END DESC) col2
FROM test;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a451353a52790ba01df61afa5ef5f5e)

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!